# Prove convergence of a sequence based on a smaller sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose that $a_n > b_n \forall n \in N$ and $\lim_{n -> \infty} b_n = \infty$. I need to prove that $\lim_{n -> \infty} a_n = \infty$ as well.

How could I handle $\infty$ sign in the limit? I cannot apply the definition of limit due to $\infty$ sign here.

Comment: The definition of the statement $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ does not require $\infty$ to be used at all.

Comment: How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Write down what it means for $b_n$ to tend to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the definition: $lim_{n \to \infty} b_n=\infty$ means that for any positive integer $N$ there exist $n_0$ such that $b_n >N$ for all $n \geq n_0$. From this it follows that $a_n >N$ for all $n \geq n_0$, so $lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=\infty$.